# Get the OS to position a wpf window

Tags: c#, wpf, winforms

Usually when you open up windows they generally go back to the position that they were in when you closed them. **How can I get the operating system to set the position of the window?** I should clarify that I am trying to open a program such as IE from my program.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you want your application window to open up at the same position it was when it was closed and you think the operating system controls this behavior. This is false, you need to implement this yourself, that is, you need to store your window state (left,right,width,height) into a settings file and then load those settings during startup.

Luckily for you, the implementation is trivial and has been answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5372951/wpf-window-location-binding) :)